# repository not found in github access denied or does not exisst

Tags: github, gitlab, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, github-for-windows

remote: The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access, make sure you're authenticated.

tried ssh gen key and deleted credential manager and origin master set url

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: How is this problem related to Gitlab or Bitbucket?

Comment: Are gitlab and bitbucket relevant to your question or did you pick tags at random?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.